# How to parse concrete value out of Either type

Tags: haskell

I have a data structure like so:

```
data MyType = Either Bool Int
```

Now I have a function like so:

```
myFunc :: MyType -> Int
myFunc mt = Right mt
```

My goal is to get the `Int` value out of the `myType` but when I try to compile this function I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int'
            with actual type `Either a0 MyType'
In the expression: Right mt
In an equation for `myFunc': myFunc mt = Right mt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Still how do I parse the value out of an `Either` type?

Comment: First thing that you need to understand is that the `Either Bool Int` value may have no `Int` in it, but `Bool`. Do you know what you want to do in this case? You can use `case` with pattern matching or [`either`](http://haddock.stackage.org/nightly-2016-03-04/base-4.8.2.0/Data-Either.html#v:either) function to write `myFunc`.

Comment: Funnily enough, you actually *can* write a total function of type `MyType -> Int`, but I think not for the reason you're expecting! You have defined a new data constructor named `Either` -- completely unrelated to the type constructor named `Either` -- which contains a `Bool` and an `Int`...

Comment: Side note: "parse" usually means converting a *string* into something.

Answer (score 3):

first note that you `data` definition is of as Cactus and Daniel mentioned - for now I assume you wanted

```
type MyType = Either Bool Int
```

---

if you really wanted `data MyType = Either Bool Int` then the situation is the same as I describe bellow with `data MyType = MyType ...`

---

as an `Either Bool Int` can have either a `Bool` value (for example `Left True`) **or** an `Int` value (for example `Right 42`) your choice is basically to *either* write a partial function:

```
myFunc :: MyType -> Int
myFunc (Right number) = number
myFunc (Left _)       = error "oho ... there is no number"
```

or you write a total-one with a default value for the bool case:

```
myFunc :: MyType -> Int
myFunc (Right number) = number
myFunc (Left True)    = 1
myFunc (Left False)   = 2
```

or you change the result type to reflect the incapability of getting some number out (using `Maybe`):

```
myFunc :: MyType -> Maybe Int
myFunc (Right number) = Just number
myFunc (Left _)       = Nothing
```

---

of course maybe you did want to have a type with **both** an `Bool` and an `Int` part - in this case change your type into:

```
data MyType = MyType Bool Int
```

and write

```
myFunc :: MyType -> Int
myFunc (MyType _ nr) = nr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data MyType = Either Bool Int
```

This does **not** mean what you think it does. This creates a new algebraic data type called `MyType`, with a single constructor called `Either` that takes a `Bool` and an `Int`. So you'll have e.g.

```
Either True 42 :: MyType
```

What you want is the ability to refer to the existing type `Either Bool Int` using a new name `MyType`, i.e. a type synonym. You can define type synonyms using `type` instead of `data`, i.e.

```
type MyType = Either Bool Int
```

this will yield

```
Left True :: MyType
```

and

```
Right 42 :: MyType
```